# How do I make a scrypt hash using Node.js's crypto library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, cryptography

```
function sha512(s){
    var sha = crypto.createHash('sha512');
    sha.update(s);
    return sha.digest('hex');
};
exports.sha512 = sha512;
```

I'm using this right now, but I want to switch it to scrypt.  How can I do that?

Comment: Node's crypto library does not support scrypt. And an implementation of scrypt into crypto doesn't seem to be in the future as scrypt isn't standardized yet. You should use [node-scrypt](https://github.com/barrysteyn/node-scrypt) which wraps the native C++ scrypt utility.

Comment: Meanwhile Node's Crypto supports [scrypt](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_scrypt_password_salt_keylen_options_callback). Node 10.5+

Comment: [scrypt-kdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scrypt-kdf) is a wrapper around the core Node.js crypto implementation which provides `kdf()` and `verify()` functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [node-scrypt](https://github.com/barrysteyn/node-scrypt).

It has clear API and good documentation.

```js
var scrypt = require("scrypt");
var scryptParameters = scrypt.params(0.1);

var key = new Buffer("this is a key"); //key defaults to buffer in config, so input must be a buffer

//Synchronous example that will output in hexidecimal encoding
scrypt.hash.config.outputEncoding = "hex";
var hash = scrypt.hash(key, scryptParameters); //should be wrapped in try catch, but leaving it out for brevity
console.log("Synchronous result: "+hash);

//Asynchronous example that expects key to be ascii encoded
scrypt.hash.config.keyEncoding = "ascii";
scrypt.hash("ascii encoded key", {N: 1, r:1, p:1}, function(err, result){
    //result will be hex encoded
    //Note how scrypt parameters was passed as a JSON object
    console.log("Asynchronous result: "+result);
});
```

Comment: Be warned: As of right now, `scrypt` does not support `node` version 0.11 or the newly-released version 0.12.

Comment: from `node-scrypt`: "#WARNING!!! This module is deprecated. Instead, use https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_scrypt_password_salt_keylen_options_callback"

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw my implementation out there: https://www.npmjs.org/package/scryptsy.

Here's an example:

```
var scrypt = require('scryptsy') //npm install --save scryptsy

var key = "pleaseletmein" //can be of type 'Buffer'
var salt = "SodiumChloride" //can be of type 'Buffer'
var data = scrypt(key, salt, 16384, 8, 1, 64)
console.log(data.toString('hex')) 
// => 7023bdcb3afd7348461c06cd81fd38ebfda8fbba904f8e3ea9b543f6545da1f2d5432955613f0fcf62d49705242a9af9e61e85dc0d651e40dfcf017b45575887
```

Documentation here: http://cryptocoinjs.com/modules/crypto/scryptsy/

Comment: How would you recommend using it in a "check user's login credentials" scenario?  I'm assuming just having a web application run the hash itself would result in major slowdown (since Node.js is single-threaded), so would you recommend offloading that work to a second, hash-only app to which the main app makes asynchronous HTTP requests?

Comment: Yep, you're correct, you'd slaughter your web app performance. I'd use cluster or child_process.fork.

Comment: Cool, I'll look into those options.  Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified [barrysteyn/node-scrypt](https://github.com/barrysteyn/node-scrypt) sync example with (de)serialization:

```
    let scrypt = require('scrypt')
    let scryptParameters = scrypt.paramsSync(0.1)

    function encode(s) {
      return scrypt.kdfSync(s, scryptParameters).toString('Base64')
    }

    function verify(encoded, s) {
      return scrypt.verifyKdfSync(new Buffer(encoded, 'Base64'), s)
    }

    // Example:
    let s = encode('my password')  // c2NyeXB0AAwAAAAI....
    verify(s, 'my password')   //true
    verify(s, 'my pa$$word')   //false
```

Tested on node 7.0.0, scrypt 6.0.3.

Comment: Using `new Buffer(string[, encoding])` is deprecated since node v6.0.0, `Buffer.from(string[, encoding])` should be used instead. [Source](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_string_encoding) Really helpful anyway; the docs are really unclear on what type should be put into the verifykdf function.